# prove if A contain not(A intersect b) then A=U

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that if $(A\cap B)^{\complement}\subseteq A$ then $A=U$.

I used De-Morgan rule on $(A\cap B)^{\complement}  $  and got
    $A^{\complement} \cup B^{\complement} \subseteq  A$.

Now I am not sure how to continue from here

If I am right I said that there are two solutions to this equations :

1) $A=A^{\complement}$

2) $A=B^{\complement}$

but I don't know how derive from here that $A=U$.

edit - U = the world

Comment: What is $U$? You need to define it first.

Comment: Note that the only way you can have $A=A^{\complement}$ is if $U=\varnothing$, in which case *all* sets under consideration are empty.

Comment: I edited the original post. U is the world .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De-Morgan rule gives you $A^c \cup B^c \subseteq A$ (and not $A^c \cup B^c= A$ as you wrote). It follows that $A^c \subseteq A$ and hence $A^c \cap A^c \subseteq A \cap A^c$, that is $A^c \subseteq \emptyset$. Thus $A^c$ is empty and $A = U$.

Comment: what is the diffrence between the = and the subseteq ? if i am proving for = isnt it applies to subseteq ?

so you assume that if you have x the belongs to (a' or b') then it belongs to a'?

Comment: Your hypothesis is $(A \cap B)^c \subseteq A$.

Comment: but on what reason can you just abandon B from $A^c \cup B^c \subseteq A$

Comment: Well, $A^c \subseteq A^c \cup B^c \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0):

You have by assumption that $ (A\cap B)^c \subseteq A $ and by definition that $ A\cap B \subseteq A$.

So there exists a set $X$ such that $X\subseteq A$ and $X^c \subseteq A$.

Then

$$U = X\cup X^c \subseteq A$$

Comment: how did you get to (AandB subseteq A ?)

Comment: That's true by definition. $A\cap B$ is a subset of $A$ and a subset of $B$

Answer (score 0):

Let me see.

we have $(A \cap B)^\complement = (A \cap B^\complement) \cup (B \cap A^\complement)$

Since $(A \cap B)^\complement \subseteq A$

Then: $B \cap A^\complement \subseteq A$

Then: $B \subseteq A$, because $B= (B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^\complement)$

Then: $(A \cap B)^\complement = B^\complement$

Then: $B^\complement \subseteq A$

But: $B\subseteq A$

Thus: $B^\complement \cup B \subseteq  A$

Thus: $ A = U $